# PCI compliance: using SSL as transport layer for RDP (Terminal Service)

Tags: ssl, remote-desktop, terminal-services

My client failed her PCI compliance audit.  The server supports Remote Desktop (Terminal Service) but only provides encryption and not authentication.  This exposes the server to Man-In-The-Middle attacks.

The supposed solution is to force SSL as the transport layer for RDP.

Anyone know how to do this?

The server runs Windows 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'old' RDP indeed does not perform authentication, but I'd be careful using SelfSSL proposed in the link sent by @ig0774 (the rest of the data in the link is correct!) If authentication is what you care about, then have your client get a *real* server authentication SSL/TLS certificate from VeriSign or Thawte or someone else listen in the list of Windows trusted CAs.

I somehow doubt PCI will allow self-signed certs. But I'm happy to stand corrected!

Comment: hi michael, i installed an SLL certificate using the following instructions, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816794#3.  but the certificate does not appear when i click "edit" from the "RDP-tcp Properties" dialog (when specifying a certificate for the SSL connection).  any clues?

Comment: where did you get the cert from? is it from a trusted cert authority? If not, you will need to copy the cert or the issuer's cert to your cert store. normally, double-clicking on the cert will add it to the correct store in Windows. lemme know.

Comment: the cert is from a trusted cert authority (rapidssl). we use it for SSL purposes to encrypt transactions for the web server.  however, the cert won't appear in the "RDP-tcp Properties" dialog, even though i followed the instructions for importing into the personal store for the server.  any clues?

Comment: It looks like rapidssl, is a subordinate CA to GeoTrust, which is support in Windows by default, but you should double beck by going here https://www.rapidssl.com/test/rapidssl.htm - if you get no errors then the root CA cert is installed. If it is, are you sure the TS server is setup for SSL/TLS? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782610(WS.10).aspx